# Javascript - Returning values from checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some checkboxes which feature days of the week.  I simply want to loop through, and display all those selected within an append.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
 <input type="checkbox" value="Mon" class="dayname" name="days[]"> M
 <input type="checkbox" value="Tues" class="dayname" name="days[]"> T
 <input type="checkbox" value="Wed" class="dayname" name="days[]">W
 <input type="checkbox" value="Thurs" class="dayname" name="days[]">T
 <input type="checkbox" value="Fri" class="dayname" name="days[]">F
 <input type="checkbox" value="Sat" class="dayname" name="days[]">S
 <input type="checkbox" value="Sun" class="dayname" name="days[]">S
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".dayname").click(function() {
   alert( $(this).attr("name") );
   $('.dayname').val();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4a3tj5ht/)

```
$(".dayname").click(function() {
    alert( $(this).attr("name") );

    $('#log').html(''); // Clears the log div

    $('.dayname:checked').each(function(e){
        $('#log').append('<p>'+$(this).val()+'</p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map().get()`:

```
$(".dayname").change(function() {
   var days = $('.dayname:checked').map(function(){
                 return this.value;
              }).get();
   console.log(days); // prints the checked checkboxes values
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".dayname").click(function() {
  alert( $(this).attr("value") );
});
```

Or

```
$(".dayname").change(function() {
if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    alert($(this).attr('value'));
}
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var checkedDays=[];
$(".dayname").click(function() {
   //alert( $(this).attr("name") );
   $('.dayname:checked').each(function(e){
      //alert($(this).val());

   });
    checkedDays.push($(this).val());
   alert(checkedDays);
});
```